# Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required Error in Laravel 5.2 Auth

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5

I just have installed laravel Authentication to my application and launch my server `php artisan serve` at URL http://localhost:8000/ and I got the following errors . 
I am using Xampp and Windows 10.And Xampp is installed in D root directory.

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   'D:\xampp\htdocs\ecom/server.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\pear')
>   in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 20):

try the following on your cmd line:

php -S localhost:8888 -t public

Make sure the "-S" is capitalized. Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 5):

Type your command line :

php -S localhost:8000 -t public

because port is not public

Comment: Please update your answer to explain why this works.

Answer (score 5):

Server.php make an **Exception** and your **Anti-Virus** like Avast delete it Automatically. Make turn off your Anti-VIrus Software. Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: This solved my issue. My Avast Antivirus had deleted ````server.php```` for some strange reason

Answer (score 0):

You see this error most time the server.php file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

> this error is occur in Laravel due to server.php file missing in your project root directory

**step1:**

> create server.php file in your project root directory

****step2****

paste below code in your server.php file

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

> this is working for me

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. Please use Markdown blockquote markup to quote text from another source. It appears you have used it to highlight your own words. You can learn more about using Markdown on this Stack Overflow Help page: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)